# How to eliminate duplicate calculation in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have a SQL that can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE LOCATE( column, :keyword ) > 0 
ORDER BY LOCATE( column, :keyword )
```

You can see there is a duplicate of "LOCATE( column, :keyword )". Is there a way to calculate it only once ?

Comment: Also, in case you didn't know, many databases let you create an index on a function or calculation.  So if you find yourself doing lots of queries based on LOCATE(column,:keyword), you could create an index where that value was precomputed and stored, to increase the speed of queries.

Comment: Are you sure that LOCATE is being called twice?

Comment: tster is correct - many sql engines will optimize that.

Comment: My purpose is not only to save calculation, but also makes the SQL clear. Because the example above is a simplified example, the actually SQL in my case may goes to 6 full lines long easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAVING works with aliases in MySQL:

```
SELECT *, LOCATE( column, :keyword ) AS somelabel 
FROM table 
HAVING somelabel > 0 
ORDER BY somelabel
```

Comment: Note that HAVING calculates the entire result set and then filters it. WHERE filters row by row, saving memory.

Comment: Not only memory, if the condition can be evaluated from a loaded indexes it might be saving I/O as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *, LOCATE( column, :keyword ) AS somelabel 
FROM table 
WHERE somelabel > 0 
ORDER BY somelabel
```

Comment: But I got an error on MySQL 

#1054 - Unknown column 'c1' in 'where clause'

The SQL is:
SELECT *, LOCATE(name, 'a') AS c1 FROM `employees` WHERE c1 > 0

Comment: This method won't work for all databases.  Some will still require you to explicitly reference the function in the ordering clause.

Comment: Does this even work for MySQL? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/select.html "It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed"

Comment: Jeff, which database support this? MySQL does not.

Comment: The AS keyword? Most should. If MySQL cannot do it, try performing the SELECT in a subquery and apply the WHERE to that.

Comment: ...see JosephStyons's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Ober has the right idea, but here is an alternative method:

```
SELECT
  t.*
 ,loc.LOCATED
FROM
  table t
  INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    primary_key
   ,LOCATE(column,:keyword) AS LOCATED
  FROM
    table 
  ) loc
  ON t.primary_key = loc.primary_key
WHERE loc.LOCATED > 0
ORDER BY
  loc.LOCATED
```